# Socket didn't connect with SSL

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, socket.io, centos

I use node.js and socket.io for our chat application and everything works good until we decide to implement SSL certificate.

Before SSL our SocketServer connect like this:

```
// Start up a Node server with Socket.IO
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080,{
  'log level':1
});
```

and Socket like this

`socket : io.connect('http://111.111.111.111:8080'),`

After we implement we setup the Proxy directives under domain.  Now any requests that are sent to https://example.com/nodejs will be passed to localhost:8080.
So I changed connection like this:

```
// Instantiate the Socket.IO client and connect to the server
socket : io.connect('https://example.com/nodejs'),
```

But the connection faild and redirect to 404 page. I don't know where can be the problem so I need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io page not found cause it listen on http server and the website js connect to it by https, this is my solution, hope it helpful:

```
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// app.use ...
// app.set ...

var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./config/privateKey'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./config/certificate')
};

var https_server = https.createServer(credentials, app);

var io = SocketIO.listen(https_server, {});

io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, callback) {
    // ...
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Some of your code help me to understand the connection with socket and now I connect it.